Python Wagtail crashes 6.3.1 "Streamfield object has no attribute 'bind_to_model'
While updating an old Wagtail website to the current version, I encounter this error, in admin/panels/group.py line 74:
AttributeError: 'StreamField' object has no attribute 'bind_to_model'
Since this is apparently in the Wagtail software as distributed, I am quite confused.

The full traceback is as follows:
Exception in thread django-main-thread:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.13/lib/python3.13/threading.py", line 1041, in _bootstrap_inner
    self.run()
    ~~~~~~~~^^
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.13/lib/python3.13/threading.py", line 992, in run
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
    ~~~~~~~~~~~~^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/Users/mike/.virtualenvs/sdenv/lib/python3.13/site-packages/django/utils/autoreload.py", line 64, in wrapper
    fn(*args, **kwargs)
    ~~^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/Users/mike/.virtualenvs/sdenv/lib/python3.13/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/runserver.py", line 134, in inner_run
    self.check(display_num_errors=True)
    ~~~~~~~~~~^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/Users/mike/.virtualenvs/sdenv/lib/python3.13/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 486, in check
    all_issues = checks.run_checks(
        app_configs=app_configs,
    ...<2 lines>...
        databases=databases,
    )
  File "/Users/mike/.virtualenvs/sdenv/lib/python3.13/site-packages/django/core/checks/registry.py", line 88, in run_checks
    new_errors = check(app_configs=app_configs, databases=databases)
  File "/Users/mike/.virtualenvs/sdenv/lib/python3.13/site-packages/wagtail/admin/checks.py", line 69, in get_form_class_check
    edit_handler = cls.get_edit_handler()
  File "/Users/mike/.virtualenvs/sdenv/lib/python3.13/site-packages/wagtail/utils/decorators.py", line 54, in __call__
    return self.value
           ^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/Users/mike/.virtualenvs/sdenv/lib/python3.13/site-packages/django/utils/functional.py", line 47, in __get__
    res = instance.__dict__[self.name] = self.func(instance)
                                         ~~~~~~~~~^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/Users/mike/.virtualenvs/sdenv/lib/python3.13/site-packages/wagtail/utils/decorators.py", line 50, in value
    return self.fn(self.cls)
           ~~~~~~~^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/Users/mike/.virtualenvs/sdenv/lib/python3.13/site-packages/wagtail/admin/panels/page_utils.py", line 73, in _get_page_edit_handler
    return edit_handler.bind_to_model(cls)
           ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^^^^^
  File "/Users/mike/.virtualenvs/sdenv/lib/python3.13/site-packages/wagtail/admin/panels/base.py", line 146, in bind_to_model
    new.on_model_bound()
    ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^^
  File "/Users/mike/.virtualenvs/sdenv/lib/python3.13/site-packages/wagtail/admin/panels/group.py", line 74, in on_model_bound
    self.children = [child.bind_to_model(self.model) for child in self.children]
                     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/Users/mike/.virtualenvs/sdenv/lib/python3.13/site-packages/wagtail/admin/panels/base.py", line 146, in bind_to_model
    new.on_model_bound()
    ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^^
  File "/Users/mike/.virtualenvs/sdenv/lib/python3.13/site-packages/wagtail/admin/panels/group.py", line 74, in on_model_bound
    self.children = [child.bind_to_model(self.model) for child in self.children]
                     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
AttributeError: 'StreamField' object has no attribute 'bind_to_model'


There is no Wagtail 6.5.1 (and won't be until at least May 2025) - did you mean 6.3.1? Also, please provide the full traceback of the error - even if the error itself surfaces within Wagtail's code, it's entirely likely that the root cause of it is something within your project.

It would also be helpful to know what version you started with and what the last version is that worked. (You are doing the upgrade stepwise, right?)

I have updated the body of the question to include the full traceback. Yes, it is 6.3.1. The site has been quietly running on "version 2-something." (I don't know what you mean by, "stepwise.") It is a fully-static site which runs on an SQLITE database file that gets uploaded along with the rest of it. (Basically, the site is a "brochure.")

The error indicates that you have a StreamField object inside a panels definition such as content_panels. This isn't valid - it should only contain panel objects such as FieldPanel.
As part of the Wagtail 2.x to 6.x upgrade process, you would have to replace any instances of StreamFieldPanel with a plain FieldPanel - my best guess is that you made a mistake while doing this, and changed StreamFieldPanel to StreamField instead.

Well, the answer is much simpler – I didn't know that I needed to do it. (The site is THAT old ...) So, I now confess that basically tried to just update Wagtail (via Pip ...) and not change anything about the site at all. "Mea culpa, of course I should have known better." Now ... Can you please point me to any published set of "upgrade instructions" that I now need to look at? (I think I need to review "everything from v2 to current.")

https://docs.wagtail.org/en/stable/releases/upgrading.html has general advice on upgrading Wagtail - see the release notes linked in the left menu for the details for each version.

Well, since this site basically is "a your-first site," I went back to the current-version documentation describing how to build one – and then test-installed a new "first site" in order to compare it to what I now have. The differences were now quite obvious.
I wound up doing quite a bit of "cruft-busting" to clean up the code and finally did so. The comments above were indeed what I needed to get on the right track. Now, the site works again.
